# Create dynamic chart with High chart mvc in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, highcharts

I am using *highcharts.js jQuery* plugin to create bar chart.

I can create a static chart but I want to create a dynamic chart. I want to draw the chart from the data read from a SQL table. How to set dynamic dataset to a *highcharts.js* bar chart.

The bellow code creates a static chart using h*ighcharts.js*. With the same code how can we create dynamic bar chart?

```cs
private List<Category> getCategory(List<ShowData> data)
    {
    Category cat1 = new Category();
    Category cat2 = new Category();
    Category cat3 = new Category();
    Category cat4 = new Category();
    if (data.Count >= 9)
    {
        inx = 1;
        cat2.name = data[inx].Cluster;
        cat2.data.AddRange(new int[] { data[inx].y, data[inx + 4].y, data[inx + 4].y });


        inx = 2;

        cat3.name = data[inx].Cluster;
        cat3.data.AddRange(new int[] { data[inx].y, data[inx + 4].y, data[inx + 4].y });

        inx = 3;

        cat4.name = data[inx].Cluster;
        cat4.data.AddRange(new int[] { data[inx].y, data[inx + 4].y, data[inx + 4].y });
        data[inx + 4].y
    }
}
```

Comment: I can help if you share your data structure and more details about the category and data

Comment: Do you use the Highcharts.NET wrapper?https://dotnet.highcharts.com/ or MVC plus highcharts.js and jQuery?